# JPA Left joining multiple OneToMany entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

HI I am trying to make a Order tracking system for the company I am working for.

Currently I need to load PO entites from my mySQL database on start up that have invoices that are either null or not 'DELIVERED' status(enum).

### My entites are as follows

```
@Entity
public class PO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name = "Customer", nullable = false)    
private String customer;

@Column(name = "PO_number", nullable = false)
private String PONUMBER;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "po",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private  List<CatogeryEntires> poCatogories = new ArrayList<>();

@Column(name = "entered_on", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime entryDate;

@Column(name = "Delivery_Date", nullable = false)
private LocalDate dd;

@Transient
private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> deliveryDate;

@Column(name = "Deliver_Before", nullable = false)
private LocalTime dt;

@Transient
private ObjectProperty<LocalTime> deliveryTime;
```

---

```
@Entity
public class CatogeryEntires {

 @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PO_CATOGERY poCatogery;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "po_id", nullable = false)
    private PO po;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "catogeryEntries", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<>();
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private int invoiceNumber;

@Column(name = "delivered_on", nullable = true)
private LocalDateTime deliveredOn;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status", nullable = true)
private InvoiceStatus invoiceStatus;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "catogery_entry_id")
private CatogeryEntires catogeryEntries;
```

---

I currently use the following native SQL statement in my data base to get the desired results

**SELECT** po_app.po.id,Customer,PO_number,Delivery_Date,Deliver_Before
,poCatogery,invoiceNumber,status

**FROM** (po_app.po left join po_app.catogeryentires on po.id = catogeryentires.po_id)

**LEFT JOIN** po_app.invoice on catogeryentires.id = invoice.catogery_entry_id

**WHERE** status is null or status != 'DELIVERED';

and I do not know to replicate this via JPQL
I try reading reference books like: Java persistance and hibernate 2nd editions" and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same book and I think that this code should work:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Your PU Name Here");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    try {

        String jpql = "SELECT p.id, p.customer, p.PONUMBER, p.deliveryDate, p.dt, c.poCatogery, i.invoiceNumber, i.status "
                    + "FROM PO p "
                    + "JOIN p.poCatogories  c "
                    + "JOIN c.invoices i WHERE i.status IS NULL or i.status != :status)";

        Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
        query.setParameter("status", InvoiceStatus.DELIVERED);
        List<Object> resultList = query.getResultList();

        System.out.println(resultList.size() + " invoice(s) found:" );

        for (Object singleResult : resultList) {
            Object[] singleRow = (Object[]) singleResult;
            ...
        }


    } finally {
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
```

You can test it with minor changes. Replace the PU name on the `EntityManagerFactory` and maybe fix some possible typo in the query.

Notice that you will get a SQL query with two INNER JOINs. I have been reading some articles and books on the subject and using a left join fetch with a where clause is invalid. Quoting "Java Persistence with Hibernate" by Gavin King et al: "*The query `left join fetch i.bids b where b.amount ...` is invalid. You can't say, "Load the Item instances and initializes their bids collections, but only with Bid instances that have a certain amount*".

Hope this helps.